# User authentication through REST web service using JSON

Tags: ajax, json, jakarta-ee

I have to authenticate to a restful Web service using the json data from my Restful webservice. I am novice to Webservice. I will appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Comment: Who is Jason and what are you doing with his data?

Comment: Sorry json generated data I mean from the WebService.

Comment: You'll have to give more details about the webserver, webservice. Actually from your question, it's unlikely that someone will be able to help. Also which json data? People can't help if they don't know exactly what problem you're having.

Comment: We have developed the apple app then I need to make user authentication using the RESTful webservice that I have made. I can use the @Path("json/application"). I am not sure how to fetch the text from iphone app and compare with the my database.